# Change options of \listofchanges in changes package

Tags: changes, trackchanges

I am revising an article using Changes Package adding corrections from several authors. When writing `\listofchanges` I get the following output:

[image]

At this point, I have two questions:

1. C1, C2, C3,... are the IDs of each author. Can I change the `\listofchanges` to print the real names of the authors?
2. Each author has an associated color during the article. Can I change the `\listofchanges` to print each line of the list in the color that is associated to the corresponding author?

As an example, the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changes}

\definechangesauthor[name={John}, color=red]{C1}
\definechangesauthor[name={Peter}, color=blue]{C2}
\definechangesauthor[name={Rose}, color=green]{C3}

\begin{document}

This is \added[id=C2]{new} text.
This is \added[id=C3]{new} text.
This is \deleted[id=C1]{unnecessary}text.
This is \replaced[id=C2]{nice}{bad} text.

\listofchanges

\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

I'd like the first row of the List of changes to be:

> Added (Peter): new ...... 1

or preferably:

> Peter (Added): new ...... 1

all of it in blue. An the same for the rest of lines, of course.

Thanks a lot!